# Write a library without class and cpp file

Tags: c++

I want to write the following function inside the header. what is the syntax to do that?

```
int added (uint8_t a, uint8_t b){
int r;
r=a+b;
return r;
}
```

Comment: what exactly is your problem? It seems to be working for me, but you need to `#include <cstdint>`. Try the following: `#include <cstdint>

inline int added(uint8_t a, uint8_t b)
{
    return a + b; }`

Comment: Just make it an `inline` function and you can put it in a header.

Comment: @Thomas Flinkow  I have a more complicated problem at hand. I need to figure out the syntax to do that, but been googling hours without finding an example. The code above is just a test.

Comment: @Atmega328 well you should be showing us your complicated problem then instead

Comment: @Atmega328 If you're including that header multiple times you need to prepend your function definitions with the `inline` keyword, such the linker doesn't try to instantiate these definiitons multiple times.

Comment: @Thomas Flinkow You are sort of right, but my situation is slightly embarrassing. Let's say my complicated problem is getting laid, but I am having problem talking to a girl. So maybe start with something simple? Let's me land first base before getting a home run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your .h has a guard.

```
#pragma once
```

Either declare the function inline in your header:

```
inline int added (uint8_t a, uint8_t b){
  int r;
  r=a+b;
  return r;
}
```

Declaring it static works as well.

```
static int added (uint8_t a, uint8_t b){
  int r;
  r=a+b;
  return r;
}
```

Or, if your function is big, or you have a circular dependency, put its declaration only in the header file.

```
extern int added (uint8_t a, uint8_t b); // extern keyword is optional
```

and the body in a cpp file

```
int added (uint8_t a, uint8_t b){
  int r;
  r=a+b;
  return r;
}
```

It's that simple.

Some compilers do not support `#pragma once` and to avoid the declarations inside the header file to appear twice when compiling a cpp (that could generate compiler warnings and errors), they use macros instead.

```
#ifndef FILENAME_H  // check if this header file was already read, using a unique macro name
#define FILENAME_H  // no. define the unique macro now, so we'll not read this section again

//  this section will only be read once.

#endif              // end the section protected by FILENAME_H
```

Comment: Can't believe it's that simple. those indef and define have made my head ache.

Comment: I was wonjdering if I shouldn't add that to the answer.  Now that you've got it.  I will,